# How to fit BB bearings to install Ultegra Crank on road bike Wilier Cento 1

Tags: road-bike, shimano, bottom-bracket, carbon

I've bought a used Wilier Cento 1 carbon road bike frame (not the new Cento1SR, but the previous model). Now I would like to transfer all Ultegra 6700 groupset components from my existing bike to it. My current bike has narrower bottom bracket frame body than the Cento 1 so it uses Ultegra BB that extends from the frame. Something like this:

[image: Ultegra 6700 BB]

Wilier Cento 1 on the other hand has a wider bottom bracket body which says *Wilier Oversize Bottom Bracket* as seen on the image below. It's about 92-94mm wide (I haven't precisely measured it, but you know what standards are out there). This is how it looks like with fitted cranks (in this case Campagnolo):

[image: Wilier Oversize Bottom Bracket]

### The main question

I know I have to buy some additional BB bearings and plugs to put them directly into the frame but I don't know whether this is a kind of PressFit system so I would require some special tools to correctly install these bearing into the frame or are they just snuggly put in so I can actually do it myself without any extra tools?

Comment: Regarding your comment about "special tools", for any PF bottom bracket, a bearing press should be used for installation.  Trying to force them in by hand or otherwise can cause uneven installation or a damaged bearing.  I speak from experience, unfortunately.

Comment: Yes I replaced my press fit BB 18 months ago. A special tool is required for removal, and another one for installation. A bit of a rip off, but easy enough to do. I found both Park and Shimano did the tools, very little difference between them in price.

Comment: AFAIK there're tools sets that come for both. Installation and removal.

Comment: @RobertKoritnik: that's true, if you buy the Park Tool removal tool for a BB86/BB30 bottom bracket, it comes with properly sized metal bushings that can also be used along with a bearing press for installation.

Comment: I have the same problem as yours. My bike frame is Imperiale with Campagnolo crankset but now I am changing it to Shimano 6800. The bottom bracket does not fit to the Shimano one. Did you solve your problem at the end? I don't even know what key words I should use to search the bearing cups for fit the Shimano crankset. BB94 seems for MTB only?

Comment: @Yang I've installed my Ultegra to the Cento1 without a problem when I got the correct bearings to fit them inside the BB using the plastic cups and spacers as shown [here](https://www.twohubs.com/pdf/Wilier-Cento-Uno-bb-diagram.pdf). **But when you say** that Shimano crankset doesn't fit your BB, can you be more specific? What doesn't fit? The bearing inner diameter or the width of your BB? If it's the bearing, then make sure you buy the correct bearing with correct inner/outer diameter and everything will likely fall into place as expected. Mine were 6805RS. 61805RS work too.

Answer (score 1):

***Edit: frame is BB94 not 386***

---

Your hollowtech bb wouldn't work as you correctly identified you'd need BB386 pressfit bottom bracket, (see exploded diagram below)you'd just need to make sure the bb you choose is compatible with your chainset and yes ideally you'd need a bottom bracket press to fit this or alternatively your lbs would fit it.

You'd need something like a bb reducer spacer kit to change your bb from bb386 to bb30...

[bb386/30 converter kit](http://www.chainreactioncycles.com/fsa-bb386-30-adapter-mw258a-/rp-prod129800?gs=1&gclid=Cj0KEQjw0fOoBRDn88Pol8bqhN0BEiQARGVJKu15XG7osROW4gP5_7UQ0_SUJwOtcno4eromiGksWBsaAgqP8P8HAQ&gclsrc=aw.ds)

and then the pressfit bb30 bb that will accept you ht2 ultegra cranks.
[FSA Reducer](http://www.chainreactioncycles.com/fsa-pf30-24-reducer-road-ee085-/rp-prod129801?gs=1&gclid=Cj0KEQjw0fOoBRDn88Pol8bqhN0BEiQARGVJKmlRRw9Utf36lHsuVGqwbScSDhUvlPUrgJ6TNRq2HjcaArbY8P8HAQ&gclsrc=aw.ds)

[image: bb386 exploded]

[bb press tool](http://www.wiggle.co.uk/lifeline-press-fit-bottom-bracket-installer/?lang=en&curr=GBP&dest=1&kpid=5360596866&sku=5360596866&ci_src=18615224&ci_sku=5360596866uk&test=%7Bproduct_id%7D&utm_source=google&utm_term&utm_campaign=Accessories&utm_medium=base&utm_content=sfoK5jtAr_dc%7Cpcrid%7C%7Cpkw%7C%7Cpmt%7C%7Cprd%7C5360596866uk)

See Also... [How to service a bb30 bb](http://www.pinkbike.com/news/Tech-Tuesday-Overhaul-a-BB30-Bottom-bracket-2012.html)

Comment: BB386 is used by the new frame models like Zero7, Zero9, Cento1SR, Cento1Air... **But not the older Cento1**. The old Cento1 doesn't have the BB386 but some other type that I don't know which one it is.

Comment: ah I see. What year is your frame?

Comment: Not sure but I think it's 2009 or 2010.

Comment: BB94 - campy: http://www.twohubs.com/product/wilier/wilier-bottom-bracket-bearing-kit/712387#.VR0WrvnF-z4    
Shimano: http://www.acycles.co.uk/shimano-xtr-press-fit-bottom-bracket-bb94-10888.html?utm_source=google_produit_cpc&gclid=Cj0KEQjw0fOoBRDn88Pol8bqhN0BEiQARGVJKm6uZKhi_F4TiUaihIb7KnconOeMwgLmeboYqksMXqIaAn0M8P8HAQ

Comment: But that's for Shimano XTR (mountain bike groupset)... According to Wilier this is the diagram that matches Cento1: http://www.twohubs.com/pdf/Wilier-Cento-Uno-bb-diagram.pdf

Comment: xtr is just the branding dura-ace and xtr press fit bearings are the same. xtr is aimed at mtb but as long as the bb is the same standard/size it will work. just like when downhill riders user road cassettes etc. I just typed bb94 shimano but I'm sure you'd be able to find a road specific dura-ace, ultegra or another shim compatible pressfit bb online.

Comment: I still think this is not a usual PressFit system. Based on the PDF diagram I've provided a link in my previous comment it seems that **bearings go directly into the frame BB body** and only plastic cups fit inside of bearings afterwards which assure there's no *rub* against the outer ring when one tightens cranks. For this reason I suppose bearings shouldn't go in too hard as they're made of metal and not plastic or aluminium. PF usually has ALU/plastic outer material so they accommodate shell while being pressed in. I've never done this myself, but that's just my reasoning. How about you?

Comment: I've only ever put press fit bearings into steel bmx frames  so I can't comment on carbon road frames but they have to be pressed in tightly with a bottom bracket press tool so there is no play i've not seen shims that go between the bearing and the frame before but i have seen the covers you mentioned that cover the bearings from getting dirt in them etc... I think this is probably one for a good LBS. or you could call these guys.. http://www.atb-sales.co.uk/wilier.html they are the uk distributor for willier they might be able to help you with part numbers etc.